# SQL Resultset (python list) to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How to convert list to a dictionary. I have a data stored in DB (sqllite) as single row and its formatted like a Python a dictionary, key:value pair.  The data looks as follows.

`"CashVal":"10000.00", "UID":"user01@test.net", "UPWD":"user01#password", "MaxSlots":"7", "MaxSlotsToFill":"5", "MinDollar":"1000"`

if I print the results set, this is what I get

`(u'"CashVal":"10000.00", "UID":"user01@test.net", "UPWD":"user01#password", "MaxSlots":"7", "MaxSlotsToFill":"5", "MinDollar":"1000"',)`

when I query it the result returned is a "list" - how can I convert that list to a dictionary? I tried using dict.fromKeys()

How to can/should I convert the list/resultset to a dictionary of key/value pair.

> > EDIT (adding code sample and output)

```
sql_stmt = "select value from configs where key = 'base_configs'"
rows = execute_sql_return_results(sql_stmt)
print (rows)
print (rows[0])
print (rows[0][0])
s_dict={str(rows[0][0])}
print (s_dict)
print (s_dict["UID"])

exit()
```

[(u'"CashVal" : 10000.00, "UID" : "user01@test.net", "UPWD" : "user01#password", "MaxSlots" : 7, "MaxSlotsToFill" : 5, "MinDollar" : 1000',)]

(u'"CashVal" : 10000.00, "UID" : "user01@test.net", "UPWD" : "user01#password", "MaxSlots" : 7, "MaxSlotsToFill" : 5, "MinDollar" : 1000',)

"CashVal" : 10000.00, "UID" : "user01@test.net", "UPWD" : "user01#password", "MaxSlots" : 7, "MaxSlotsToFill" : 5, "MinDollar" : 1000

set(['"CashVal" : 10000.00, "UID" : "user01@test.net", "UPWD" : "user01#password", "MaxSlots" : 7, "MaxSlotsToFill" : 5, "MinDollar" : 1000'])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gp_model_trader.py", line 283, in 
    print (s_dict["UID"])
TypeError: 'set' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Comment: I'm not sure how it would work with whatever encoding you use for quotes, but something like `d = json.loads('{' + data + '}')` would work for your simple example.

Comment: Please include the exact code. Joachim's suggestion is right. It is a question of having {} around your data. But I want to see why you get () around your key value pairs. To convert a list of lists to a dictionary do    l=[[4,5],[6,7] ] d = dict(l). d will be {4:5, 6:7}.

Comment: : inside () or [] produces a syntax error.  Apparently, : can be used only within {}.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, you need to take the string and wrap `{` and `}` around it so that it now looks like a `Json` representation of a dictionary. It can now be converted from a `Json` string back to a dictionary using `json.loads`:

```
import json

s = u'"CashVal":"10000.00", "UID":"user01@test.net", "UPWD":"user01#password", "MaxSlots":"7", "MaxSlotsToFill":"5", "MinDollar":"1000"'
d = json.loads('{' + s + '}')
```

It appears you are running Python 2. You will end up with a dictionary whose keys and values are `unicode` strings. If you want these to be `str` types, the keys and values can be converted with a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {str(k): str(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```